# Difference between H Pylori Breath Test and SIBO 24h PH Breath Test

Tags: sibo, h.-helycobacter-pylori, helicobacter-pylori, small-intenstines

I have been told that these too tests test the same condition/symptom:

1. H Pylori breath test
2. SIBO 24 hour PH breath test

Can anyone confirm if a H Pylori test is the same as a 24 Hour PH Breath Test?

Comment: Welcome to Health, Olly. I've allowed myself to format and cut down your answer so that only the relevant part remains, which allows other users to use information gained here too. If you happen to disagree with my edit, please feel free to either roll it back or [edit] the question yourself. If you have questions about how the site works, [meta] is the place for you.